# Modify a plugin to open external links with iframe using https and not http?

Tags: https

I'm using this wordpress old plugin which opens external links on my website in an iframe (ex: example.com/external/https://externalsite.com).

The only issue is: If I use https (SSL) on my website, external links (https://example.com/external/...) will redirect me to an 404 error page. External links are working fine only if I use http on my website (http://example.com/external/...).

Link to the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-external-links-bar/

Can someone tell me exactly what to modifiy in the plugin in order to make the plugin work with https only? (the plugin doesn't have many lines of code) I think we need to modify the following file: wp-elb.class.php

I only found these lines of code related to http. Thanks in advance.

```
if ( !$this->totallink )
        $this->totallink = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ( !$this->actuallink ){
        $url=str_replace($this->basedir,'',$this->totallink);
        $this->actuallink = $this->cleanUrl($url);
    }
```

---

```
function cleanUrl($url) {
    if ('' == $url) return $url;
    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%]|i', '', $url);
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a');
    $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url);
    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);
    $url = (!strstr($url, '://')) ? 'http://'.$url : $url;
    $url = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z]{2,8};)/', '&#038;$1', $url);

    return $url;
}
```